# Get path data for multiple nodes

Tags: d3.js

I have a series of paths, how can I get the node data for all the paths. I can only seem to get the path information from the last path:

```
var paths = svg.selectAll('.path')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
    .attr('d', line)

console.log(paths.node())
```

Comment: That's what you're passing in with `data`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, my data contains many elements, but `paths.node()` only returns one path. How can I get the node data for each path?

Comment: Your data contains the nodes for each path. Is that not what you mean by "node data"?

Comment: Each datum contains all the nodes for a single path. Each data element contains one path. When I run the code above I get back a single path for one data element, eg. `<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M30.5,267.5c29.094-21.022,61.667-46.152,98.618-49.914"/>`. How can I get the data for all the paths?

Comment: You should be able to see the individual paths by doing this: `.attr("d", function(d) {console.log(this); return line(d)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data for all paths by iterating over the elements in your selection, e.g.

```
var pathData = [];
paths.each(function() { pathData.push(this); });
```

or, if you want just the `d` attribute, something like

```
var pathData = [];
paths.each(function(d) { pathData.push(line(d)); });
```